# Converting a word document to XML format while preserving font information

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, xml, file-conversion

I need to convert a Word document into an easily parseable format, so I chose XML. I found a [tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140221%28v=office.10%29.aspx) which works, but it doesn't tell me which font the text is, which is my main method of parsing. Is there any tool that preserves this information or a link to a tutorial that provides code?

Answer (score 1):

Word 2012 (and Word 2007 via add-in) can store Word documents in WordML (.docx) with is an xml format.

This format is easily parsable - there are libraries for several languages, and some, like .NET have built-in parsing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You need an accompanying XSL document, this should help: 
http://webdesign.about.com/cs/xslinformation/a/aa051198.htm

Comment: Could you add some more detail about how I would use the XSL document?

Comment: Have you tried the online example at W3C, they have a demo you can try out? I've never had to style XML so dont have a personal example I can show you but looking at this demo it looks pretty straight forward.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: Not sure what context is your doing this but if it is web development its much easier to style the outputted XML via CSS